# AngularJS animated item reappears after animation ends

Tags: angularjs, css, animation, css-animations

I am having an issue I cannot seem to figure out. I am animating an item on `ng-hide`. The animation runs fine when showing the element, but when hiding the element, the element **briefly shows again before it disappears**.

```
.spinner-container.ng-hide-remove {
    animation: splat-in 1s linear forwards;
}

.spinner-container.ng-hide-add {
    animation: splat-out 1s linear forwards;
}
```

The element itself:

```
<div class="row spinner-container" ng-hide="fadeOut">
    <div class="spinner"></div>
</div>
```

Here is [a Plunkr illustrating the problem](http://embed.plnkr.co/d34bFPQjZalhhoqkWN6z/preview).

Comment: Please check this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OUgU2vFOweKPESBekjkS?p=preview), if this is what you wanted.

Comment: That plunkr seems exactly the same to me. Note that after the item has animated out, it takes a little while and it is visible again. After another while it disappears again. The only thing you seem to have done is add `-webkit` prefixes to everything. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Yea. Sorry, I didn't notice the item coming back again. Will try to help ya. Check it again.

Comment: No changes as far as I can tell.

Comment: Hi - Sorry that couldn't find out the exactly where the bug is in keyframes. But the bug is due to the keyframes. When I use a fadeOut effect instead of splat-out, I don't find the element to appear again once it's faded out. [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OUgU2vFOweKPESBekjkS?p=preview) with fadeOut where the item doesn't appear once the keyframe ends.